# Java - this sorting method is a mystery

Tags: java, sorting, methods

im stuck with the following code, it should insert a key/pointer combination into a node of a datastucture and keep it in a sorted order, however the order seems random and i just CANT figure out whats wrong!

```
public void add (int val, Node no) {
    // Find the index where to insert
    int maxval = 0;
    for (int o = 0; o < this.values.length; o++)
        if (val < this.values[o]) {
            maxval = o;
            break;
        }
    // Move all the data from the chosen index one spot forward
    for (int o = this.values.length-1; o > maxval; o--) {
        this.values[o] = this.values[o-1];
        this.children[o] = this.children[o-1];
    }
    // Insert the value
    this.children[maxval] = no;
    this.values[maxval] = val;
}
```

Comment: Inserting a value will throw away (overwrite) the greatest value. Is that the intention?

Comment: There are sorted sets available in java. You don't need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Well one problem is that if `val` is greater than *all* the current values, you end up with `maxval = 0`. You could fix this by initializing `maxval` to `values.length - 1` to start with, perhaps...

Another problem is that you're effectively losing the original value of `values[values.length - 1]` - it's being overwritten with the earlier value, but nothing's copying that value elsewhere. What's the desired behaviour here?

Comment: Ah yes, that must be the answer!, Ill just add an if statement for that at the beginning of the method, also, the point in the code where the method is called is not accessed when the current node is full so that isnt the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: i just changed
if (val < this.values[o]) {
to
if (val < this.values[o] || o == this.size()) {
with a size method i already had, so when its larger then all of the values, maxval will be the value of the first empty spot

Comment: I don't think that's the solution Jon meant. Why not just initialize int maxval = values.length - 1; in the 3rd line like he suggested?

Comment: didn't you mean that `maxval` should be initialized by `values[values.length - 1]` (the index of the greatest value) and not by `values.lengh - 1`?

Comment: @denisk: No, because `maxval` is actually meant to be the *index* for the new value, not a value. But it changes if there's a `size()` involved... I think the suggested change should be okay.